Ubuntu LibreOffice: German spell checking doesn't work
Extension German dictionary doesn't work.
Here is some more information. I deleted the existing German dictionary and added the one LibreOffice offered.

Just found a way to manage this problem. Extinguished one Extension and installed a new one.

This might be good info for someone to read in the future but not as written. The question needs details such as the version of Ubuntu and Libreoffice being used. Same with the answer it needs to be in the answer field. At the bottom of the question you will see an answer your own question option, use that and add the complete answer. What did you delete what did you install.

Sorry, English isn't my mother-tongue. So I can only speak in short sentences. I admit, this was very short. Here are some more information: I deleted the existing German dictionary and added the one,LibreOffice offered. The was it. Hope, I expressed myself in an understandable way. - Heiho

OK if I make it an answer are you ok with that?
